# get multiple rows from a row cell values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this

```
Id   Flag1   Flag2     Desc 
--   -----   ------    ----- 
1      1       1        XXX 
2      1       0        YYY
```

and I want result like this

```
Id   Flag1   Flag2     Desc
--   -----   ------    -----
1      1       1        XXX
1      1       1        XXX
2      1       0        YYY
```

where each entry for flag is true.

How to do this?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question... You want to multiply by 2 entry with flag2 = 1?

Comment: Your result is not clear.

Comment: Only 2 flags used? Only multiply by 2 or may be more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you have 16 flag columns, you can use a numbers table like this to reduce the total `UNION ALL` Queries. just add the total flags in a row and compare it with the `row_number` of the Numbers table.

**Query**

```
;WITH Numbers AS (SELECT 1 rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 ),
Numbers1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY c1.rn) as rn FROM Numbers c1 CROSS JOIN Numbers c2)
SELECT Id, Flag1, Flag2, [Desc] FROM flagtable 
INNER JOIN Numbers1 N ON N.rn <= CONVERT(INT,flag1) + CONVERT(INT,flag2)
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

---

You can use `UNION ALL`. Something like this.

**Query**

```
SELECT Id, Flag1, Flag2, [Desc] FROM flagtable WHERE Flag1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Flag1, Flag2, [Desc] FROM flagtable WHERE Flag2 = 1
ORDER BY Id
```

**Output**

```
Id  Flag1   Flag2   Desc
1   1   1   XXX
1   1   1   XXX
2   1   0   YYY
```

Comment: Thanks. its working but assume that there are around 16 flag columns. i need to check them all

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tbl(id,flag1,flag2,cnt,descp,idx) AS
  (SELECT id,
    flag1,
    flag2,
    CASE
      WHEN Flag1=1
      AND Flag2 =1
      THEN 2
      ELSE 1
    END cnt,
    descp,
    1
  FROM test2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id,
    a.flag1,
    a.flag2,
    b.cnt,
    a.descp,
    b.idx+1
  FROM test2 a
  JOIN tbl b
  ON (a.id     =b.id
  AND b.idx+1 <= b.cnt)
  )
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id
```

**Result set of the query**

[image: Result set of the query]

Comment: it would be simpler to just to have 2 separate `union all` each having its own `WHERE Flag = 1` rather than self joining

Comment: Looks like it wont work if both flag1 and flag2 have 0 as value with simple uinion

Comment: you are right but we don't know what the OP wants in that case.

Comment: Thats correct we dont know the output but as per the screen shot in the question I understood that if flag is false dont repeat the record. And I assumed that flag is true only if boolean values in flag1 and flag2 are derived to true.